# How to pulse the last thread in waiting list?

Tags: c#, locking

I'm trying to access some resource concurrently, so I'm using `lock`.

```
object lockObject = new object();
lock(lockObject)
{
    //Acquire some resources and do some operations  
}
//Pulse only the most recently joined thread in waiting list
```

But what I want is simply pulse only last thread (most recently joined thread in waiting list) and ignore other threads (deadlock, abort or starvation isn't the concern here). 
One option I can think of is using message queue and ignore all the messages except processing last one. Other than that how can I simply pulse the very last thread and just ignore other threads?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement this. Here's one way.

You'll have a 'thread manager' which each thread will call to 'wait' for a resource.

This thread manager will essentially manage a [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx) of [WaitHandles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx). 
When a thread calls the manager, it will create a new `WaitHandle`, and push it to the stack, then give the instance to the thread, which it can wait on.

When your code wants to let the last waiting thread to `pulse`, it will pop the top most wait handle from the stack, and `signal` it.

(Note that this architecture relies on the calling thread to wait on the WaitHandle.)

HTH